# How to get the keys with same name in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I want to delete all the snapshots from EC2 except the one which has tag `Do-Not-Delete` I am getting all the snapshots from the EC2 using `boto3` and then I want to remove the tagged snapshots from the list.

```py
snaps_to_remove = ec2_client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=account_ids)
    for snap in snaps_to_remove['Snapshots']:
            #Filter Snapshots 
            print(snap['Tags'])
```

Output

```
[{'Key': 'Do-Not-Delete', 'Value': '1'}, {'Key': 'Project', 'Value': 'Traindex'}]
[{'Key': 'Project', 'Value': 'Internal'}, {'Key': 'Do-Not-Delete', 'Value': '0'}]
[{'Key': 'Project', 'Value': 'Internal'}, {'Key': 'Do-Not-Delete', 'Value': '1'}]
[{'Key': 'Do-Not-Delete', 'Value': '0'}, {'Key': 'Project', 'Value': 'Internal'}]
[{'Key': 'Project', 'Value': 'Internal'}, {'Key': 'Do-Not-Delete', 'Value': '0'}]
```

In the above code, I am unable to filter the snapshot using `print(snap['Tags'][0]['Key'])` because different order of the tags.

Please help me filter and remove the elements from the array which have a specific value.

Update:
snaps_to_remove data coming from the call

```
{'Snapshots': [{'Description': 'Created by CreateImage(i-099fc2ede043fb22f) for ami-08c0fe2a97c67473f from vol-005d5e895fe1fc2e6', 'Encrypted': False, 'OwnerId': '825617374672', 'Progress': '100%', 'SnapshotId': 'snap-06a2b3cc3f10242b3', 'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 29, 6, 40, 39, 391000, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'State': 'completed', 'VolumeId': 'vol-005d5e895fe1fc2e6', 'VolumeSize': 250, 'Tags': [{'Key': 'Do-Not-Delete', 'Value': '0'}, {'Key': 'Project', 'Value': 'Internal'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'Internal API'}]}}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: post the sample input data and expected outptut

Comment: @komatiraju032 I am not expecting any output. 
Updated the question with the JSON data

Comment: can you clarify what exactly are you trying to remove ?

Comment: @komatiraju032 I am trying to remove the element from the list which contains Tags and in the subkey of tag looking for 'Do-Not-Delete' tag with value of 1.

Comment: what if `key=Do-Not-Delete and value=0` ? add the expected output how your snapshots looks after the deletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isn't this just the following?

```
to_dump = []
for ss in snapshots:
  if not any(tag['Value'] == '1' for tag in ss['Tags'] if tag['Key'] == 'Do-Not-Delete'):
    to_dump.append(ss)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly but if you want to find the 'Do-Not-Delete' value in any of the two dictionaries in each list entry you could do something like this:

```
for first, second in snaps_to_remove['Snapshots']:
    if first['Key'] != 'Do-Not-Delete' and second['Key'] != 'Do-Not-Delete':
        # delete this
```